# Status Bar Appears Over My View in IOS 7

Tags: ios7

In my IOS7 app,Status Bar Appears Over My View.After googling I found that I should use

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

in viewDidLoad method and working fine.But I have over 30+ view controllers in my app.Is there any easy way to write the above piece of code in a single place instead of writing it in all classes ?

Answer (score 1):

firstly your are create the catgory class of `UIViewController like UIViewController+layoutVC`

and wirte the code in `UIViewController+layoutVC.m` file

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```

and no need to write the code in all view controllers.

Comment: Thanks.Then we need to write the code in all view controllers.right ?

Comment: Not working.It's showing a warning near viewDidLoad "UIViewController+UIViewController_layoutVC.m:12:1: Category is implementing a method which will also be implemented by its primary class"

Comment: don't worry for alert ,code is work on my device, i think you have a little mistake

Comment: reset the simulator , again try

Comment: send the simple code on my email id deepeshjain@outlook.com if  u want ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39904/discussion-between-deepesh-and-jeff)

Comment: THIS IS TOO DANGEROUS!!! You shouldn't override a method which you should call the super instead. Compiler will give you warning about this. If you override a UI method in a category class, you will probably be handling with unexpected behaviours eventually.